# how to insert a vertex in between 2 vertices with edge. Azure Cosmos DB [GREMLIN API]

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, gremlin

[image: diagram]

so from the diagram i would like to save previous versions of `formula vertex` that is modified by `user vertex`.

So here are the things that i want to do if a formula is modified

- clone the previous value of `formula vertex` and add a `previos_value` edge from the latest `formula vertex` to the previous `formula vertex`
- add a `modified` edge from the `user vertex` to the previous `formula vertex`
- transfer all outgoing and ingoing edges from the previous `formula vertex` to the latest `formula vertex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a simple helper method to do the job:

```
modify = { user, product, version ->

  g.V().has("software","name",product).as("s"). /* this would be your formula vertex     */
    valueMap().
      by(unfold()).as("sm").

    addV("software").as("ns").                 /* create a new vertex                    */

    sideEffect(select("sm").unfold().as("kv"). /* copy properties from the old vertex    */
               select("ns").
               property(select("kv").by(keys),
                        select("kv").by(values))).

    property("version",version).               /* set version on the new vertex          */

    select("s").
    sideEffect(                                /* transfer out-edges                     */
      outE().as("e").
      sideEffect(
        select("ns").
        addE(select("e").by(label)).
          to(select("e").inV()).as("ne").
        select("e").properties().as("p").
        select("ne").
          property(select("p").key(),
                   select("p").value())).
      drop()).
    sideEffect(                                /* transfer in-edges                     */
      inE().as("e").
      not(outV().where(eq("s"))).              /* exclude self-referencing edges        */
      sideEffect(
        select("ns").
        addE(select("e").by(label)).
          from(select("e").outV()).as("ne").
        select("e").properties().as("p").
        select("ne").
        property(select("p").key(),
                 select("p").value())).
      drop()).

    select("ns").
    addE("previous_value").to("s").inV().      /* add edges to previous version and user */
    addE("modified").
      from(V().has("person","name",user)).

    iterate()

}
```

In practice it would look like this:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> 
gremlin> modify = { user, product, version ->
         ...
.....39> }
==>groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1@7523d5a1
gremlin> 
gremlin> modify("marko","lop","v2")
gremlin> 
gremlin> g.V().has("name","lop").
......1>   inE().outV().
......2>   path().
......3>     by(values("name","version").fold()).
......4>     by(label).
......5>     by(elementMap())
==>[[lop],previous_value,[id:13,label:software,name:lop,lang:java,version:v2]]
==>[[lop],modified,[id:1,label:person,name:marko,age:29]]
==>[[lop,v2],created,[id:1,label:person,name:marko,age:29]]
==>[[lop,v2],created,[id:4,label:person,name:josh,age:32]]
==>[[lop,v2],created,[id:6,label:person,name:peter,age:35]]
```

Comment: Thank you!! but how do i make this work with azure cosmos db[gremlin api]?

Comment: If it doesn't work as-is, let me know which steps are not supported in Azure (I don't have a test environment for Azure).

Comment: It says `Unsupported groovy language rule: 'closure' text: '{user,product,version-`

Comment: Well, you don't need to send the whole lambda over the wire. The code that I wrote in Groovy could be on your client-side (e.g. written in Java), it's just used to build the whole traversal which then can ultimately be send to Azure.